# Odata v4 orderby expand webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

so I am using webapi with the latest version of odata

I am trying to sort and filter my expand,

http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?%24select=OrderID&%24expand=Order_Details(%24select=UnitPrice;%24orderby=UnitPrice%20desc)

not getting any errors as the data comes back with no issue, however the the orderby inside of the expand dose nothing.

is this sort allowed?
if not do you know of a workaround?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported yet, see this issue to track the progress. https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/557

Comment: FYI this was implemented and deployed late 2015.