# Can not $orderby in $expand in ODATA v4

Tags: odata

Is it not supported to use $orderby in $expand clause? The following link does not sort the OrderID in reverse order.

[http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$select=CustomerID&$filter=CustomerID eq 'ALFKI'&$expand=Orders($select=OrderID;$orderby=$it/OrderID desc)](http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$select=CustomerID&$filter=CustomerID%20eq%20'ALFKI'&$expand=Orders($select=OrderID;$orderby=$it/OrderID%20desc))

But it does work without $expand clause like this:

[http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$select=OrderID&$orderby=OrderID desc](http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$select=OrderID&$orderby=OrderID%20desc)

Comment: OP your syntax is correct for the protocol, the service you have referenced does not fully implement the specification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Odata v4 orderby expand webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897342/odata-v4-orderby-expand-webapi)

Answer (score 1):

This was added in [Microsoft.Data.OData v5.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/5.8.4) and isn't supported in the northwind v4 demo at services.odata.org. See the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/557) for more details.

### NOTE:

http://services.odata.org/V5/Northwind/Northwind.svc is no longer being maintained.
Please refer to the service listing at odata.org for the latest supported OData V4 reference APIs: https://www.odata.org/odata-services/

Comment: Note that even at the time that OP posted, many implementation libraries did support ordering of projected navigation collection items, the odata.org demo service has still not been updated with this functionality.